# Does Tkinter validation have to be heavy-handed?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm designing a "settings" frame for a Python/Tkinter app that lets the user specify an IP address, port number, and a couple other configurable options.  I want to validate the user entries before letting the user close the frame to apply them.

Based on what I've read up on (and tried) so far with the `Entry` widget's `validate` and `validatecommand` options, the only choices they offer are "heavy-handed" validations.  The kind where the user is blocked from leaving the Entry widget (or even typing any more keystrokes) until the entry is valid.  This is exactly the behavior I avoid when designing a GUI because it's annoying as all get-out for the user.

I'm planning on switching over to using .trace methods to keep watch on the values, and just disabling the "OK/Apply" button until all of the entries in the frame are valid.  Before I do that though, I wanted to know whether I'm missing anything with regards to the built-in validation options.  Is there an option I missed that's less heavy-handed?

Comment: Can setting an [`invalidcommand`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TkCmd/entry.htm#M16) callback offset the heavy-handedness?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you should do this, but you can attach an `invalidcommand` handler that will act on the entry *as if* everything was fine.

Example script:

```
import Tkinter as tk

def onvalidate(d,i,P,s,S,v,V,W):
    # only lowercase is valid
    valid = (P.lower() == P)
    # set red background if invalid
    newcolor = 'red' if not valid else default_color
    root.nametowidget(W).configure(background=newcolor)
    return valid

def oninvalid(d,i,P,s,S,v,V,W):
    #called if widget is invalid
    widget = root.nametowidget(W)
    # S is the character that *would* have been
    # inserted or deleted, but won't because it is invalid
    # So we do it ourselves
    if S:
        if d=='0':
            widget.delete(i, len(S))
        elif d=='1':
            widget.insert(i, S)
    # Changing the text clears the 'validate' value
    # so we have to reset it
    widget.after_idle(lambda W,v: root.nametowidget(W).configure(validate=v), W, v)

root = tk.Tk()

valhook = (root.register(onvalidate), '%d', '%i', '%P', '%s', '%S', '%v', '%V', '%W')
invhook = (root.register(oninvalid), '%d', '%i', '%P', '%s', '%S', '%v', '%V', '%W')

entry = tk.Entry(root, validate="key", validatecommand=valhook, invalidcommand=invhook)

default_color = entry.cget('background')

entry.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

This will create an entry that will have a red background if invalid and a white background if not, but the text will still be inserted or deleted even if the entry is invalid.

Comment: This is nice, I used a similar approach in my old VB6 apps -- hadn't quite worked out how to do it in Tkinter.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the validation feature without the "heavy-handedness". Have your validation always return True after setting the state of the ok/apply button.

Comment: Thanks, I wouldn't have thought of this.  I can just point all the Entry widgets to the same common routine (like I'd planned to set up for the alternative with trace).

Answer (score 1):

If you use trace, then you have what you want without needing to use Tkinter's validation at all. Make all traces go to the same function, where you test and validate all your values as you wish, and according to that enable or disable the ok button.

Comment: I figured that -- I just wanted to know whether the Tkinter validation was a viable option before I switched over.